# Python: how do index a list with another list, then index it again with another list?

Tags: python

I would like to index a list of space-separated numbers with another list, then index it again with another list.

```
z = ['1 2 3 4 5', '6 7 8 9 10', '11 12 13 14 15','16 17 18 19 20']
x = [2,3,4]
y = [3,2,1]
i = []
k = []
```

Here's my attempt:

```
for a in y:
    i.append(z[a])
for b in i:
    j = b.split(" ")
    for c in x:
        k.append(j[c])
```

I want the result to be [18,14,10] instead I get ['18','18','18','13','13','13','8','8','8']

Comment: Can you give more descriptive names to the variables in your code ? It will make the code more understandable (and easier to debug and answer your question).

Comment: your attempt output is  ['18', '19', '20', '13', '14', '15', '8', '9', '10'] so im confused

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension is one neat way to do it, zipping x and y means you do not need the intermediate object which is a list of lists so scales pretty poorly.

`[z[j].split(" ")[i] for i, j in zip(x, y)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `zip()` function to loop through both your iterables at the same time and use the two indices to append values to the k-list directly. Without using an intermediary i-list.

```
z = ['1 2 3 4 5', '6 7 8 9 10', '11 12 13 14 15','16 17 18 19 20']
x = [2,3,4]
y = [3,2,1]
i = []
k = []

for a,b in zip(y,x):
    j = z[a].split(' ')
    k.append(j[b])
```

That will result in `k==['18', '14', '10']`

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating twice the second time, which will extract all three indices for the space separated lists. Instead try this:

```
z = ['1 2 3 4 5', '6 7 8 9 10', '11 12 13 14 15','16 17 18 19 20']
x = [2,3,4]
y = [3,2,1]
i = []
k = []
for a in y:
    i.append(z[a])
for e,b in enumerate(i):
    j = b.split(" ")
    k.append(j[x[e]])
k
>>['18', '14', '10']
```

Here I'm doing enumerate to track the iterations and slice the corresponding indices from the provided list.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what u wanted to do

```
z = ['1 2 3 4 5', '6 7 8 9 10', '11 12 13 14 15','16 17 18 19 20']
x = [2,3,4]
y = [3,2,1]
i = []
k = []

for a in y:
    i.append(z[a])
print(i)
for (b,c) in zip(i,x):
    j = b.split(" ")
    k.append(j[c])
print(k)
```

Output `['18', '14', '10']`